# Javascript question: How do I duplicate user input into a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hidden-field

How can I pass input from a text-type input element into a hidden input element in the same form on a site that has jquery installed?

Comment: When? As they're typing? As they submit the form?

Comment: Why: One field is used to group articles by category, and this form allows users to input new categories, where title = article category. When: It needs to be submitted with the form-- both fields are required to create a new record in the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggered when the text changes:

```
$("#text_id").change(function(){
  $("#hidden_id").val($("#text_id").val())
});
```

Triggered when the form submits:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(){
  $("#hidden_id").val($("#text_id").val())
});
```

Check out other [jQuery Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Events).

Comment: The form id is generated uniquely each time by a script. I've tried the text-change trigger method, and I can't get any data submitted in the #hidden_id field. Is this dependent on a certain version of jquery? My script tag links to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: The text change event is a little tricky.  The text isn't usually considered changed until the text box loses focus.  I'm not sure if the event is triggered when the text box is changed and then the form is submitted without the text box first losing focus.  Why can't you copy the value after the form has been submitted in the script that receives the GET or POST request?

Answer (score 4):

If `input_1` is the id of the input you want to populate, and `input_2` the id you want to populate **from**, use:

```
$("#input_1").val($("#input_2").val())
```

Comment: Shouldent you put it under some kind of event, like "submit" or "keyup"?

Comment: $('input_2').keyup(function(){ $('#input_1').val($('#input_2').val());});

Comment: I tried this code with the keyup event, and I still can't get any data submitted in the hidden field. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to figure out if it's the event or if it's the function code. You could also put this in the form's onsubmit event to reduce overhead. I also believe this event is more reliable as I've had some troubles catching keyup events myself, but I haven't fully investigated the cause.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Javascript. How can I identify whether the problem is in the event or function code? Here is an example with two input fields that I want to keep in sync: http://designop.us/jtk-temp/21.htm

Please let me know if you notice any errors in my code, or if you can tell me how to pass input from the first input element into the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id_of_hidden_input").val($("#id_of_text_input").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only one field of each type:

```
$('input[type=hidden]').val($('input[type=text]').val())
```

If you have more add IDs to selectors