# Passing variable from one form to another without submit

Tags: php, variables, post, echo

I have two forms on a page. 
I want the "`amount`" entered from the top form to be passed through to a hidden value in the second form. All before anything is submitted.

The first form

```
<form id="form1"> 
<input required="required" placeholder="10" type="number" name="donation_amount" id="donation_form_amount">
</form>
```

And when someone types in their Donation Amount from that form, I want it to pass through to

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $donation_amount;?>">
</form>
```

As you can see, i tried doing "`echo $donation_amount`" but that did not work. 
How do I pass through the amount from the first form to the hidden value of the second form? Without submitting the first form.

Comment: requires javascript. but why you just dont submit a single form to paypal is unclear

Comment: There are two options for submitting payment. By credit card, which runs through one payment gateway, and secondly through paypal. But I only want one place where they enter their amount...

Comment: I am assuming I would be using AJAX to complete this?

Comment: paypal takes credit card, you dont need an account. and no you dont need ajax, plain old js is fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202555/javascript-question-how-do-i-duplicate-user-input-into-a-hidden-field